# Creating a PHP API: Checking from which server the API Request comes from

Tags: php, api, curl, dns, request

I'm creating a PHP API for a website and I'd want to restrict the API access to domains that are registered on our server (in order to prevent abusing of API usage). So, this is my approach right now, and well, it should look pretty good on paper.

1. The API is setup at `api.example.com`.
2. A user that wants to use the API registers with us, adds his domain and gets an API key.
3. The user of the API will use his API key to encrypt his request data (via `mcrypt`) and sends it, via `cURL` to `api.example.com`.
4. **My server checks from which domain this API request comes from** and matches that domain to an API key in the database. If there is an API key, the API decrypts the request via `mcrypt` with that key and then using the same method encrypts and sends the result.

I'm stuck on step 4. Originally, I planned to use HTTP_REFERER to check it, but since cURL doesn't send one by default and it could be easily faked in the user-side code (CURLOPT_REFERER as far as I remember), I am stuck here.

Is there a method to know from which domain this API request comes from? I see that it can be done with some popular APIs like the reCAPTCHA one. Checking the _SERVER["REMOTE_HOST"] isn't really an option because of shared hosts (they have the same IPs) so this would not be able to prevent abuse (which would originate mostly from shared servers anyway).

Is there such a method to check for it? Thanks!

Comment: This might be of interest: http://phpweby.com/software/ip2country

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Shafee has a good idea it just needed some tweaking. We're focusing on the visible part of the API call, which is the API key. This is visible in the URL and tells the API *who* is requesting the data. Rather than trying to prevent others from stealing this key and running their own cURL call with the domain they intercepted it from, we *can* 'just add' another key to the mix, this one not visible to those interceptors. I'm not saying stop checking where the request is coming from, it's still a good way to kick out invalid requests early on in the script, but with a second key, you guarantee that only the person requesting the data actually knows how to get the data (you're trusting them not to give it away to anyone).

So, when the user registers for a key, you're actually assigning two different keys to the user.
**API_KEY** - The public key that connects you to your domain. The system looks up the domain and key provided in order to find the next key.
**MCRYPT_KEY** - This is the key that will be used to actually encrypt that data via Mcrypt. Since it's encrypted data, only the requester and the server will know what it is. You use the key to encrypt the data and send the encrypted input with your API key to the server, which finds the key that it needs to decrypt that input via the API key and domain (and IP) that have been provided. If they did not encrypt the data with the proper key, then decrypting with the correct key will return gibberish and the `json_decode()` call will return NULL, allowing the script to simply return an 'invalid_input' response.

Ultimately with this method, do we even need to check where (domain/IP) the request is coming from? Using this method it really comes down to the API users not giving away their API/MCRYPT key pair to other users, similar to not giving away your username/password. Even so, any website can easily just go sign up to get their own key pair and use the API. Also to note, the API will not even return anything useful to their server unless the user on their end logs in using the correct username and password, so their end will already have that information. The only thing new our server is really returning is their email address upon successful validation of the user. Having said that, do we even need to use cURL? Could we not simply use `file_get_contents('http://api.example.com/{$API_KEY}/{$MCRYPT_DATA}')`? I realize I'm asking more questions in my answer...

Comment: The usage of file_get_contents *is* a problem in most shared hosting servers, hence we avoid using it. cURL is the proper way (except sockets) to connect to most web-based (HTTP) APIs anyway. file_get_contents is a dirty hack. :p

Answer (score 3):

You can varify what ip the request comes from, and you ofen can do a ptr search to get a domain name for that ip, but probely the ip adress have more then one domain, and you end up whit the wrong one, so i recomendate that the client send his domainname in the reques, maybe whit HTTP_REFERER, and that you make a dns check if that domain points to the ip asking for it, but notice that a domain, like google.com, can point to more then one ip.
(the ip could probely be faked to, whit some good hacking skill, but thats out of my knowledge)

Comment: So you mean registering an IP/APIKey, then reverse-lookup the IP to its domains, match the domain (sent through HTTP_REFERER) with the list of domains, and if it matches, go for it? This is a solution, too, yeah, but its a little bit complex. Thanks! :)

Comment: I fail to see how this resolves the issue. The same problem exists. Multiple websites can run from one IP. So if you just use the IP to lookup all domains hosted on that IP address and check if the domain provided is in that list, how is that any different from just checking if that IP matches the API key given? Anyone on the server will still be able to call the API by simply specifying that domain in the cURL call.

Comment: a domain name is just an alias for an ip-adress, if more then one domain points to the same ip-adress, that just like me having more then one nickname, if you call me "puggan", "tobbe" or "thorbjörn", i may react diferent, but if i call you, you have no way to see if its "puggan", "tobbe" or "thorbjörn" thats calling, they are all me

Comment: A better expanle for domains and IPs would be a residential address. There may be 4 people living in the house and a couple of them may have nicknames that also point to that address, but in the end there are still 4 *different* people living there. Your example would assume that all domains pointing to a single IP are owned by the same person, when that may not be the case.

Comment: in my exemple i made one person = one server, but as you say, the server can be shared, but you never see the owner connect to you, its the server that connects to you, and you have no ide what user are logged in at the server when the server starts to talk to you

Answer (score 3):

How about introducing a second variable like lets say an `app id`. When a user registers her domain, associate this id with the domain. The user needs to submit the `app id` with each request without encryption along with the encrypted api call. Then you can look up the `app id` get the `app secret` and try to decrypt?

Comment: That then would pretty much defeat the purpose of having an API key in the first place, sorry. I am using API Key (and checking domains to match) in order to make sure that there is no abuse. With this case, then one could just fake the AppID and APIKey like I pointed out with the REFERER solution. Thanks though! :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to best prevent abuse of your API, limit either the speed of requests, or limit the number of requests they can make. If someone is stupid and shares their API key, they'll only be limiting their own API usage, making it more economical for people who intend on abusing the API to get their own key.

Plus, what if someone decides to implement a desktop application using your API? Surely they won't require their users to send their IP addresses to them so that they can whitelist them?

Also, you can combine limiting speed/limiting requests, and limit speed based on the number of requests like how Verizon limits the speed of their 3G network if you pass a certain amount of data usage.

Comment: Abuse isn't just that. If the API key is shared, security is compromised. That's another primary thing to worry about.